# Apache: How to Serve Both PHP and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a PHP site https://example.com.
I have a MEAN stack application subdomain http://team.example.com. It uses APIs provided by nodejs on port 3000.

I'm facing a problem when running the application on http://team.example.com where the Nodejs API is not reachable .

added the following to Apache Config File:

ProxyPass /node/ http://localhost:3000/

I am sending api request from angular side with the following:

team.example.com/node/users/login

APIs reached successfully via postman , but fails on browser

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In Apache Config file, at the tag of 'VirtualHost *.80' I added the following.  
- ProxyPass /node/ http://localhost:3000/
I am also sending requests to Node Api from example.com/node/. Now it works in a great way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue, I'm assuming that you are using express framework in your node service.
See the following sample code to know how to solve CORS issue for browser.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'); 
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); 
  next();
});

app.post('/test-cors', function (req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'status': "OK" }));
});

// Create http server and run it
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log("Listening on 8081");
});
```

In above sample code you need to focus on following code lines:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'); 
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); 
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

For using the proxy you have to enable the proxy module in apache. After that restart the apache.

If you are using ubuntu os run following command

> sudo a2enmod proxy &&
>   sudo a2enmod proxy_http

After this, you have to run

> sudo service apach2 restart.